# Raspberry Pi ssh X11 Forwarding

Tags: ssh, pi-4, ubuntu, xorg

I have a raspberry pi 4 (4gb) as my local machine and am trying to ssh in to an ubuntu laptop with X11 forwarding.

I can connect just fine but I have the classic empty $DISPLAY variable and I'm not sure why. -X and -Y flags don't help.

Additionally, when I try to connect with ssh -v -X -Y user@host I don't see the expected debugging message about "Requesting X11 forwarding". Also, even if I set the $DISPLAY variable manually:

```
DISPLAY=<raspberrypi_ip>:0
```

I still receive the following when ssh into the server and trying to run xclock

```
xclock
Error: Can't open display:
```

Here are some details

**Server side (ubuntu laptop)**

/etc/ssh/sshd_config

```
X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
```

which xauth

```
/usr/bin/xauth
```

**Client Side (raspberry pi)**

~/.ssh/config

```
ForwardX11 yes
ForwardAgent yes
```

Comment: Don't use both `-X` and `-Y`, it makes no sense. Do you have `ForwardX11Trusted ` in `sshd_config`? If not, I suggest you use only `-Y`. If yes,  `-X` and `-Y` are the same.

Answer (score 4):

Setting `$DISPLAY` variable to an IP address won't work unless you also run `xhost` on the X server (which is the Pi, aka "Client Side") to add the remote host to the authorized hosts list. You will also need to generate an `Xauthority` file using `xauth generate`, copy that file to the server and add the token on the "Server Side" using `xauth merge`. I think you will have to restart the X server on the Pi as well.

However, what you want most of the time is to use localhost forwarding, where `$DISPLAY` is set to a local unix socket (e.g. `localhost:10.0`). In this case, `xauth` should be called to add the cookie which you get from `ssh` on connection, and the most common reason why `ssh` didn't do it for you automatically is that it hasn't receive the cookie in the first place.

Check `~/.ssh/rc` (or `/etc/ssh/sshrc` if the first file doesn't exist) on the "Client Side": it must contain something equivalent to

```
echo add $DISPLAY $proto $cookie | xauth -q -
```

Note that *equivalent* doesn't imply any degree of similarity, e.g. `xauth -q - << EOF $stuff EOF` could be equivalent.

If the `xauth` command is there, then you likely didn't get the cookie. Verify that you have `X11UseLocalhost=yes` on the "Server Side": most guides on setting the X11 forwarding simply assume it's there. You also need `localhost` (and `inet6:localhost` if you use IPv6) to be present in `/etc/X0.hosts` on the "Client Side".

In any case, remember to set up [`pam_xauth`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_xauth) on the "Server Side" if you want to run GUI apps remotely as any user, not just the one you logged in with: make sure it is installed and edit `/etc/pam.d/su` to add the line

```
session optional pam_xauth.so
```

P.S. There appear to be [problems](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/629659/pam-xauth-isnt-working-with-sudo-unsupported-authorisation-protocol) with `pam_xauth`, as a workaround, you could add the following lines to `~/.bashrc`:

```
if [[ -n $SSH_CONNECTION ]]; then
    sudo touch /root/.Xauthority
    sudo xauth add $(xauth list | tail -1)
fi
```

This shares your Xorg cookie with a specific user (`root`).